# AppCenterPush does not register device and does not receive notification - Swift 4

Tags: swift, push-notification, visual-studio-app-center

I'm following [microssoft's step-by-step to use AppCenterPush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/ios), however when trying to insert "MSPushDelegate.setDelegate (self)" Xcode returns me the following error "Type 'MSPushDelegate' has no member 'setDelegate'".
I think I can not register the device or receive notification because I can not associate MSPushDelegate.

***My current code:***

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import AppCenter
import AppCenterAnalytics
import AppCenterCrashes
import AppCenterPush

@UIApplicationMain class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MSPushDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Clean notifications
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    application.cancelAllLocalNotifications()

    //enable notification (used for local notifications)
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .sound, .badge], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    // Notification by AppCenterPush
    MSPush.setDelegate(self) // this line show the error: "Type 'MSPush' has no member 'setDelegate'"
    MSAppCenter.setEnabled(true)
    MSAppCenter.start("{MyAppSecret}", withServices: [
        MSAnalytics.self,
        MSCrashes.self,
        MSPush.self
        ])
    return true
}
```

**My code to show the notification:**

```
func push(_ push: MSPush!, didReceive pushNotification: MSPushNotification!) {
    print("Working")
    let title: String = pushNotification.title ?? ""
    var message: String = pushNotification.message ?? ""
    var customData: String = ""
    for item in pushNotification.customData {
        customData =  ((customData.isEmpty) ? "" : "\(customData), ") + "\(item.key): \(item.value)"
    }
    if (UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background) {
        NSLog("Notification received in background, title: \"\(title)\", message: \"\(message)\", custom data: \"\(customData)\"");
    } else {
        message =  message + ((customData.isEmpty) ? "" : "\n\(customData)")

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel))

        // Show the alert controller.
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: But the tutorial  says you should write `MSPush.setDelegate(self)`. So by instead saying `MSPushDelegate.setDelegate(self)`, you are not even copying and pasting the tutorial code correctly.

Comment: I have tried to use "MSPush.setDelegate (self)" but I got the same error "Type 'MSPush' has no member 'setDelegate'"

Comment: Can you tell us which version of XCode and App Center SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 9, but the version of the SDK I do not know, why when inserting in podfile I inserted only "pod' AppCenter / Push '"

Comment: The version of App Center SDK is 1.8.0

Comment: The sending of the notification was solved, was an inconsistency with the certificate, however I could not relate the delegate 'MSPush.setDelegate (self)', then the func push is not executed, in it is the code that I wanted to execute when the notification arrived.
Do you know any other way to intercept the notification and get the message sent?

Comment: Have you tried without all the local notification stuff? Like removing `// Clean notifications` and `//enable notification (used for local notifications)` code blocks but keep the MSPush delegate and try a remote push to see if it works in that case.  Also please note that if an alert is shown you need to click on it to trigger the callback (the callback is fired without click only if application in foreground at push time).

Comment: I was able to send the notification through the AppCenter, but I can not relate the delegate, I need it when I receive the notification to get its message and also perform an action . Currently, when I send a notification it is automatically issued without performing any action.
I believe it is not executing the PUSH function because it is not linking the delegate ... to solve this problem should I create a new question?(ps. sorry for my English, im Brazilian)

Comment: Hi, I would recommend creating either a ticket on the app center support (blue chat button on any page of the portal) or create the ticket on https://github.com/Microsoft/AppCenter-SDK-Apple/issues so that collaborators not monitoring stack overflow can help you.